# Android: Set Pc as an android USB Host device to test android phone app in USB accessory mode

Tags: android, usb, adk

I am creating an app (running in USB accessory mode) that will recognise when a specially made device (that I am also working on) is plugged in and connect to it.
I have written code in the app for this recognition to happen but now need to test it and the specially made device is not made yet.

So, I was wanting to test my app by somehow setting my PC up to be recognised as a usb host device that my phone can connect to, I spent a long time googling and looking for a way to do this or a different way to test this but came up empty.

How do I set my PC up in this way to test my app or what would be a good way to test this automatic usb connecting?

Thank you kindly,

EDIT:
Even the name of a cheap device that runs in android usb host mode would be sufficient as I could still just plug that into my device to check if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to emulate USB Host mode with the Emulator and setting up a bridge with an emulated device on the PC. This is not possible (yet).

See [Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) documentation. In the "What's not supported section" it is said that virtual hardware is not supported for USB.